# Decaying a templated type's value in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm implementing a simple variant class (mainly for practice) and I've come to a problem with type decaying. I would like to create a constructor that takes a sub-type of the variant and constructs it accordingly ([case (4) here, the converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant)).

For copying and moving, I have a helper class that contains functions like this:

```
static inline void copy(std::size_t old_type_id, void* old_data, void* new_data);
static inline void move(std::size_t old_type_id, void* old_data, void* new_data);
```

So I'm passing everything as a `void*` for simplicity. My converting constructor looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
variant(T&& v)
    : type_id{ typeid(std::decay_t<T>).hash_code() } {
    if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) {
        helper_type::copy(type_id, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&v), &data);
    }
    else {
        helper_type::move(type_id, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&v), &data);
    }
}
```

My idea was to check if this is a reference, because then we can only copy, otherwise move. But because `v` is a templated parameter, there is no automatic decaying of types, and if I try to pass a C-style string, I get errors like:

> cannot convert from 'const char (*)[6]' to 'void *'

Is there a way to do this kind of conversion without specializing every decaying type?

Comment: You should use `const void`. BTW, `hash_code` doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @liliscent Thank you, indeed the const was missed from the copy method's old_data parameter. Thank you for the extra info too, I'll have to come up with a better mechanism then. Would you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@liliscent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8605791/liliscent) says, you need to use `const void*`.

This is because even though `void*` can accept any type of pointer, it is still bound to the rules that state that a conversion from `const T*` to `T*` is ill-formed if you don't use `const_cast` (which you shouldn't in this case).